# reduce a sequence with two types to a sequence with one

Tags: scala, sequence

I have the following sequence:

```
parameter:Seq[(Int, String)]
```

How can I convert this to a sequence consisting only of the Strings found in parameter?

Comment: `parameter.map{_._2}` or `parameter.map{ case (_, s) => s}`

Comment: And another remark: This sequence already contains objects of a single type: `(Int,String)`. Just because a tuple is a "product type" composed of two different types (here `Int` and `String`) does not mean the tuple type is two different types. It's a single type combining two other types in one.

Answer (score 0):

Hope following example will help. Answer already suggested by senia

```
val parameter= List((1, "A"),(2, "B"))
val indexlist = parameter.map(_._2)
println(indexlist)
```

Comment: How about `val parameter = List((1,"A"), (2,"B"))` for much better code?  Also, write `x +: xs` instead of `xs.+:(x)`.  And there's no reason to wrap this in an `object`.